# Как развернуть React приложение?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как развернуть собранное React-приложение на компоненты?
Приложение имеет вот такой вид в собранном состоянии у меня на локальном сервере:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно развернуть его на компоненты и исправить там кое-какие детали. Как можно это сделать?

Comment: Ваш скриншот абсолютно не информативный.

Answer (score 0):

Если коротко - никак.

Ищите исходники и пересобирайте как нужно.

Если исходников нет и очень нужно - ищите в коде нужный компонент и исправляйте вручную. Может занять много времени.